# MVC6 TagHelpers with disposable

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In the older MVC HTML Helpers, one could use `IDisposable` to wrap content - for example the `BeginForm` helper would automatically wrap `*stuff*` with a closing `form` tag

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
   *stuff*
<% } %>
```

Is this wrapping of content supported with MVC6 TagHelpers?
For example I would like this

```
<widget-box title="My Title">Yay for content!</widget-box>
```

to be expanded into a bootstrap widget-box with wrapping divs:

```
<div class="widget-box">
    <div class="widget-header">
        <h4 class="widget-title">My Title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-body">
        <div class="widget-main">
            Yay for content!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with TagHelpers?

**Solution**: I have baked @DanielJG's answer into a [working demo on github](https://github.com/neutmute/aspnetv5demo/) which consumes [WidgetBoxTagHelper.cs](https://github.com/neutmute/steelcap/blob/master/src/SteelCap/Ace/WidgetBoxHelper.cs) (will stay current with Beta/RC/RTM as am using the lib in my production app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag helpers have to implement the interface `ITagHelper` (as pointed by **@NTaylorMullen**, the `TagHelper` class is just a convenience class you can use when implementing it) which forces you to use the methods `Process` and `ProcessAsync`, so you cannot rely on adding contents in a `Dispose` method.

However you have full control over the output content so you can replace/modify it as you need. For example, a quick approximation to your widget tag helper (**Using the 1.0 version of the framework**):

```
[HtmlTargetElement("widget-box")]
public class WidgetTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var outerTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        outerTag.Attributes.Add("class", output.TagName);
        output.MergeAttributes(outerTag);
        output.TagName = outerTag.TagName;

        //Create the header
        var header = new TagBuilder("div");
        header.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-header");
        header.InnerHtml.Append(this.Title);
        output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent(header);

        //Create the body and replace original tag helper content
        var body = new TagBuilder("div");
        body.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-body");
        var originalContents = await output.GetChildContentAsync();
        body.InnerHtml.Append(originalContents.GetContent());
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(body);
    }
}
```

In your razor you will have:

```
<widget-box title="My Title">Yay for content!</widget-box>
```

Which will be rendered as:

```
<div class="widget-box">
    <div class="widget-header">My Title</div>
    <div class="widget-body">Yay for content!</div>
</div>
```

Don´t forget to register the tag helpers in your assembly by adding a `@addTagHelper` directive to the **_ViewImports.cshtml** file. For example this will register all helpers in my application:

```
@addTagHelper *, WebApplication2
```

**OLD beta7 code**

- In beta7 you had to use the `[TargetElement]` attribute.
- The TagBuilder class had a `SetInnerText` method you could use to set its context as text.

The code looked like:

```
[TargetElement("widget-box")]
public class WidgetTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private IHtmlEncoder encoder;
    public WidgetTagHelper(IHtmlEncoder encoder)
    {
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var outerTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        outerTag.Attributes.Add("class", output.TagName);
        output.MergeAttributes(outerTag);
        output.TagName = outerTag.TagName;

        //Create the header
        var header = new TagBuilder("div");
        header.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-header");
        header.SetInnerText(this.Title);
        output.PreContent.SetContent(header);

        //Create the body and replace original tag helper content
        var body = new TagBuilder("div");
        body.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-body");
        var originalContents = await context.GetChildContentAsync();           
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            body.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.StartTag;
            body.WriteTo(writer, encoder);
            originalContents.WriteTo(writer, encoder);
            body.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.EndTag;
            body.WriteTo(writer, encoder);
            output.Content.SetContent(writer.ToString());
        }                            
    }
}
```

**OLD beta5 code**

- There was an `InnerHtml` property in the tag helpers.
- There was a `ToHtmlString` method in the tag helpers used to render them as html.

The code looked like:

```
[TargetElement("widget-box")]
public class WidgetTagHelper: TagHelper
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var outerTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        outerTag.Attributes.Add("class", output.TagName);
        output.MergeAttributes(outerTag);
        output.TagName = outerTag.TagName;

        //Create the header
        var header = new TagBuilder("div");
        header.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-header");
        header.InnerHtml = this.Title;
        output.PreContent.SetContent(header.ToHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal).ToString());

        //Create the body and replace original tag helper content
        var body = new TagBuilder("div");
        body.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-body");
        var originalContents = await context.GetChildContentAsync();
        body.InnerHtml = originalContents.GetContent();
        output.Content.SetContent(body.ToHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @fiat. Its interesting to play with asp .net 5 :). BTW, I just saw your github repo, good idea!

Comment: An extra note: To be a valid `TagHelper` you just need to implement the `ITagHelper` interface. The `TagHelper` class is just a nice base implementation :)

Comment: In BETA 8 TagBuilder has no SetInnerText method anymore so the code doesn't work. You only get the innertext

Comment: @firste, I finally got the time to try the RC1 version of ASP 5 and update the code